# Criar tipo um menu, mas com sinal de (+) (TreeView)

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc-5

Uso Bootstrap 3.1, Entity 6.1, Visual Studio 2013, MVC5, JQuery e etc... Bem, preciso fazer uma consulta, de forma que quando a tela é carregada, ela consiga carregar algumas informções, como medicamento(Descrição) e outras informações, mas em separado. Para não trazer tudo, como em um grid, meu gestor pediu para que eu fizesse assim. Um sinalzinho de mais(+) e quando eu clicar nele, aí sim, expandir tudo. Há algum componente para isso? É possível fazer no ASP.NET e MVC? O Bootstrap faz isso?

Comment: Você parece estar falando de um TreeView

Comment: `"É possível fazer no ASP.NET e MVC?"` O único limite para o que você pode fazer com .NET está em quanto esforço você pode ou deseja empenhar na solução ;)

Answer (score 1):

Você pode utilizar o `.slideToggle()` no jQuery no nome do produto. 
Tratando a lista de medicamentos com um `foreach`, você pode pegar o `ID` do produto e associar a um componente para mostrar via jQuery pelo `.slideToggle()`.
Por exemplo:

View

```
     <div id="medicamentoGeral-@medicamento.ID">
       <span>Medicamento Nome
         <a href="#" class="mostrarCompleto" id="@medicamento.ID"> + </a>
       </span>
      <div class="medicamentoItem">
        "Medicamento"
        "Descrição"
        "Qualquer coisa"
      </div>
    </div>
```

jQuery

```
     $(".medicamentoItem").hide();
     $('.mostrarCompleto').click(function () {
     var id = this.id;
     var item = ("#medicamentoGeral-" + id);
     $(item + " .medicamentoItem").slideToggle();

});
```

Comment: Atualizei! Conseguiu?

Comment: Então, como eu disse, qualquer função jquery que escrevo começando com $, dá erro de: $ is not defined. Acabei de testar um outro exemplo também e dá o mesmo erro.

Comment: Entendi.
Você não está trabalhando com razor? Se não, troque por <% %>, Exemplo: @medicamento.ID vira <%medicamento.ID%> ou <%=medicamento.ID%>, não lembro direito. Sobre jQuery, se o problema é começar com $, declare uma variável e atribua a classe/id em questão como valor.

Comment: O erro é meu. Eu tenho 3 layout de páginas em meu projeto(Master). Acontece que em todas eu tenho os includes de javascript básico em todas e nessa esqueci de adicionar o jquery-2.1.0.min.js, por isso o erro do $. Resolvi essa parte. O outro exemplo meu funcionou, mas o seu ainda não.

Comment: Entendi. Aqui eu estou trabalhando exatamente com isso da seguinte forma jsfiddle.net/3stwhLmv . Não vai funcionar é claro, mas para você visualizar o código na integra e ter uma noção melhor. Isso gera essa página congressoconsulfarma.com/Web/saiuMidia é claro que o exemplo não tem muito haver, mas da para entender que tem como utilizar da forma que você quer

Answer (score 1):

## Há algum componente para isso? É possível fazer no ASP.NET e MVC?

Sim, chama EasyUI. Como você está trabalhando em cima de ASP.NET MVC, ele está disponível como um pacote NuGet:

> https://www.nuget.org/packages/EasyUI

Exemplo: http://jeasyui.com/demo/main/index.php?plugin=Tree&theme=default&dir=ltr&pitem=

Há também uma outra *Collapsible List* (este é o termo em inglês) que não possui cara de lista de diretórios:

> http://code.stephenmorley.org/javascript/collapsible-lists/

## O Bootstrap faz isso?

Nativamente não, mas existe esse projeto no GitHub que cria *TreeViews* no Bootstrap:

> https://github.com/jonmiles/bootstrap-treeview

Se precisar que eu empacote como Package no NuGet, é só falar.

Comment: Vou pesquisar cada reply de vocês e depois posto o resultado. Talvez faço isso hoje ainda. Obrigado.

Comment: Ainda não consegui fazer funcionar os exemplos tanto do Cigano quanto o do Rafael.

Comment: @pnet Defina melhor "Ainda não consegui fazer funcionar". O que você mudou no código? Como você alterou a `View`? Quais foram os dados utilizados? A gente não tem como saber que erro você está tendo. É preciso ser mais específico.